# use ppi to get logical resolution

Tags: screen-resolution, ppi

I am trying to emulate the Samsung Galaxy Tab S 10.5 , and I have no idea what the screen resolution is to create an emulator.  This model seems to be left off any list I found.

Full Spec & Details http://www.gsmarena.com/samsung_galaxy_tab_s_10_5-6438.php

The screen has been given the specs:

```
2560 x 1600 pixels, 10.5 inches (~288 ppi pixel density)
```

If I use 2560 x 1600 pixels as the screen size, its obviously too big.  How can I work out its Device pixel Ratio?  Does the ppi have anything to do with it?

The Nexus 10 is 1280 x 800, but how can I get an exact for this or any device?

EDIT

Looking at the Nexus 10 (also made by samsung), it has the same 2560 x 1600 pixels, a Device pixel Ratio of 2, a slightly smaller screen, and a slightly bigger ppi of 300.  So it would make sense this tab would also be Device pixel Ratio of 2.  But is there a way to work out Device pixel Ratio from specs?

Comment: Why is it 'obviously too big'? The screen size *in pixels* is what it is -- that *is* the resolution. You seem to assume all screens are the same; but I'm pretty confident your desktop screen is not 288 dpi but only something like 120~150 dpi.

Comment: its a handheld 10.5" screen.  A screen with a width of 2560 pixels would be like a new big iMac.  It may be the physical resolution but not the logical.

Comment: But if you assume these are the actual values and do the calculations, you will find the estimated ppi value works out. What exactly is "logical resolution"?

Comment: basically how the screen displays actual pixel size, or 1 css pixel.  Its physical pixels/device pixel ratio.  But I cant find the ratio for this device.  It will be between 1&3, probably 2